# Unclear issue after installing django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, installation, installation-path

I tried to install django after python installation (3.4.0 version), the problem began when i tried to run the simple command: "pip install django" via the cmd - it did nothing (descending line and writes nothing). I forced it to apply the installation using the command: "python -m pip install django". Although it was declared that the installation was successful, when I run, for example, the command: "django-admin --version" it did nothing as well, but when i run the command: "python -m django-admin --version", it says that: "python.exe: no module named django-admin".

In general, each command associated to pip or to django does not work, such as:
pip help, pip X ot django X

Ps. I added the paths in 'Path' of the User Varuables and System Variables:
C:\Python34; C:\Python34\Scripts

Comment: Can you confirm the user account that you are running has the permissions to execute Python?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response - yes, i can assure that

Comment: did you have previous versions of python? install a fresh stable version of python ( like 3.5 or ... ) and restart ( installation will set your env valiables, but be sure about that ). the check "pip" command, it should show pip options.

Comment: I uninstalled all previous versions using revo and only then installed the 3.4.0 again  - i tried with 3.5 before that as well, same results, it didn't do anything when i run any command with "pip x".

Answer (score 0):

For you and possible future users asking similar question:

Only the `pip` command runs the 2.7 Python interpreter. You are using the 3.4 version, so instead of pip you have to use the `pip3.4` command.

Why? Python 2.7 is not compatible with the 3.x and higher versions.

In your case Django is installed only for the 2.7 version and if you run the python3.4 command, Django is not installed ("no module named django").

Comment: Thank you for your response - but when i'm trying to run commands using pip3.4 they ain't recognized, for example: "pip3.4 install django" gives the same result and does nothing - same goes for any command starting with "pip3.4".

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'd be tempted to downgrade to Python 2.7 if you're just getting started. It'll probably save you a lot of problems with pip and Django.

Comment: Maybe it's all broken after you modified the path. Try to reinstall Python3.4. Have you ever installed pip? Btw "django-admin" is command for terminal, not librabry (module).

Comment: I'm able to import it with no problems at all, maybe i really should downgrade to 2.X :/

Comment: No you shouldn't. Show printscreens from terminal, what happens after these commands "pip3.4 install django" and "django-admin startproject blabla".